# How to catch Ext.Panel scroll event in ExtJs 6?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I do not know how to properly catch scroll event on a standard `Ext.Panel` element. Currently, I'm doing it like so:

```
listeners: {
    afterrender: function () {
         this.body.on('scroll', function(){
             ... do what I want ...
         });
    } 
}
```

But the problem is, it catches only vertical scrolling. However, when I scroll my panel horizontally, I can not catch it. So, what is the right way to do this?

Comment: Try this.getEl().on('scroll', function(){})

Comment: Thanks! I do it like so - `this.body.dom.onscroll = function () {....` and it works.

Comment: Here is an example of the sencha way hope it helps https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/24rr